# What was the political organization of small villages and towns in medieval Transylvania by the end of the 15th Century? (Both Saxon and non-Saxon)

Tags: middle-ages, political-history, hungary

I've been trying to find out about the political organization of small villages in medieval Transylvania during the time the region was part of the Hungarian Kingdom (more precisely during the end of the 15th century, after King Matthias' death - though any information on this century would be appreciated). I'm interested in villages that are mainly populated by Saxons (the German people who settled in parts of Transylvania) and Romanian villages.

Here is what I have figured out: Transylvania was governed by a [Voivode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivode_of_Transylvania), which represented the interests of the King. In truth, however, the Voivode spent a lot of time in Hungary and it was [the Vice-Voivode who took care of things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice-voivode_of_Transylvania).

The Saxons were a people that settled in Transylvania around the 12th century and had some privileges over the Romanians - privileges afforded to them by the king. [The Saxons answered to their Count (Comes Saxonum) who presided in a city named Sibiu](https://www.academia.edu/5350862/Government_and_Law_in_Medieval_Moldavia_Transylvania_and_Wallachia_edited_by_Martyn_Rady_and_Alexandru_Simon_2013_):

> "The charter of 1224 lists the main privileges and obligations of the
> hospites Theutonici of Sibiu. In the fourteenth and fifteenth
> centuries, these rights and duties were extended to all Saxons of
> Transylvania.7 First, as mentioned above, the king recognised the
> local autonomy of the German settlers of Sibiu, placing them under his
> direct authority. He exercised his authority upon his German subjects
> through a royal count who was subsequently appointed, more or less
> every year, from the ranks of his courtiers. The king gave to his
> hospites the right to elect their priests and judges, who also
> discharged an administrative authority. They also had the right to use
> their German customary law (which was in fact based on the law of the
> Saxon miners of Silesia and Bohemia). The county of Sibiu was
> permitted use its own seal, which implied recognition of its corporate
> right of self-government."

That's the broad strokes of the higher political organization. But what about the lower ones? I'm interested in knowing the political organization of towns and small villages in Transylvania.

I've seen some places mentioning the [figure of a mayor](https://mek.oszk.hu/03400/03407/html/80.html), others mentioning [the figure of a judge and a council](https://www.academia.edu/5350862/Government_and_Law_in_Medieval_Moldavia_Transylvania_and_Wallachia_edited_by_Martyn_Rady_and_Alexandru_Simon_2013_):

> "In 1366, when the gerébs still functioned as town judges, the office
> of mayor was established in Szeben, Segesvár, and Brassó, essentially
> to represent the interests of the increasingly prosperous merchant
> class. As the gerébs gradually faded in importance, so did the office
> of town judge, leaving the mayors in control of the towns, and
> therefore of the seats. At the same time, all Saxon towns except
> Beszterce retained the subordinate office of 'Hann', or village judge
> (villicus), which dated from their village origins. Beszterce had
> neither a mayor nor a Hann, but only a town judge. This indicates that
> although it existed as a Saxon settlement prior to 1241, its
> development — unlike that of the other Saxon towns — was interrupted
> by the Mongol invasion. The king therefore had to found a new town,
> with a fresh population, as he did in the case of Kolozsvár, where the
> offices of mayor and Hann were equally unknown. Obviously, in both
> cases the original population had been annihilated by the Mongols."
>
> "In Hungary, the community (universitas) would yearly elect a judge
> (judex/iudex, maior villae or villicus) as its representative, while
> the local comes (lord or ispán) lost all jurisdiction over the
> townspeople and the land granted to them. Along with the judge, the
> townspeople elected a council made up of twelve sworn men (iurati).
> The combined authority of the two institutions extended over all
> matters affecting the legal and administrative affairs of the
> community. Afterwards, some towns instituted a larger or ‘outer’
> council, made up of one hundred or so members, which took over the
> right to pick the judge and sworn men."

But I can't find a source that explains this in detail, only tangentially. If anyone can shed some light in the issue, it would be greatly appreciated.

P.S.: For what's worth, in the Netflix Castlevania's animation the characters get to a small Wallachian village whose leader is called "the judge" (while in a bigger town - Targoviste - they called their leader "the mayor"). But it is worth noting that Wallachia and Transylvania were different places with, possibly, different political structures at the time.

Comment: I usually like to pop in here to make sure every question has at least *some* feedback, so the poster knows how they are doing. In this case, all I really have to say is that I like the question (+1), and wish I had the time to do the research to answer it myself. Hopefully someone will get it for you.

Comment: Thank you @T.E.D.! Hopefully so

Comment: Do you mean "small villages and small towns" or "all villages and towns, big and small"?

Comment: Transylvania had a very large diversity and also autonomy, reflected also in the fact it kept its autonomy after the fall of Hungary. German towns were the biggest and had special/separate status. But the [Szekely Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Székelys) had a special status too. Romanians lost their privileges/rights gradually at higher level but some kept regional privileges like [Fogaras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fogaras_County#History) and all had (especially religious) village autonomy.